# How to parse GeoJSON data and save coordinates into PostGIS geometries format?

Tags: java, spring, postgis, geojson

How to convert GeoJSON to readable format so I can save in PostGIS database.

I have some GeoJSON like this.

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "name": "Some Boundary",
  "crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
      "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
    }
  },
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "State_Name": "ABC",
        "State_Code": "01"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              76.767318,
              33.228753
            ],
            [
              76.767318,
              33.228753
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "State_Name": "DEF",
        "State_Code": "02"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              79.008814,
              31.115041
            ],
            [
              79.008814,
              31.115041
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "State_Name": "GHI",
        "State_Code": "03"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              76.942524,
              30.383268
            ],
            [
              76.850815,
              30.717589
            ],
            [
              76.852673,
              30.718222
            ],
            [
              76.853471,
              30.718813
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here I want to filter out **geometry** `coordinates` and `type`, and then I can save in to PostGIS db like this.

`ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((0 1, 2 5, 2 7, 0 7, 0 1))')`

Here is what I am trying.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
JSONArray features = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("features");

JSONArray coordinates = (JSONArray) geometryObject.get("coordinates");
JSONArray coordinate = (JSONArray)  coordinates.get(0);

String geoString = "'"+str+"'((";

for(int j=0; j<coordinate.size(); j++){
    JSONArray tempArr =   (JSONArray) coordinate.get(i);
    geoString = geoString +  tempArr.get(0).toString() +" ";
    geoString =  geoString + tempArr.get(1).toString();
    int len = coordinate.size() - 1;
    if(i < len){
        geoString = geoString +",";
    }
}

geoString = geoString +  "))'";
```

Is there any effective way to do that because this is breaking in some cases.

Comment: Is the geojson consumed via rest api ?

Comment: ANish I am reading from the geojson file.

Comment: This is the solution -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53957417/parse-geojson-file-with-java-topology-suite-or-geotools

Comment: I have tried that but got stuck. let me try again and ya thanks again.  @AnishB.

Comment: The geojson sample in your question is malformed so I cannot even test it.

Comment: I managed to fix your geojson and it's missing a closing `]` for the `features` key, so none of the code you provided actually matters because it would result in a JSON Exception from the very first line. Please provide the full geojson next time or at least make sure it is valid json.

Comment: Also, the GeoJSON data itself is invalid. In order to form a Polygon, there need to be at least 4 or more positions (meaning at least 4 arrays of coordinates, where the 4th coordinates == 1st coordinates to close the Polygon). You can read more from the official GeoJSON format specification here: [link](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-3.1.6). It is a good question but there are just too many issues with what you're providing, which makes me doubt any of the stuff you provided is your work; hence, I am going to downvote this question.

Comment: @QuanBui yes you are right. I have just removed the long coordinates so it can fit in SFO  question. my code is working for `pilygon` but it is failing for `MultiPolygon` type.

Comment: @David Firstly, there are two types of `Polygon`: with holes and without holes. For Polygons without holes, there is simply only one Array of positions - a geojson position is also an array `[longitude, latitude]`. In order to parse a Polygon, you need logic to cover both of those cases. A `MultiPolygon` is just an array of `Polygon`- which also can be with/without holes. You can read more about them here: [Polygon](https://macwright.com/2015/03/23/geojson-second-bite.html#polygons), [MultiPolygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43645172/geojson-multipolygon-with-multiple-holes)

Comment: I fixed your geojson in your question to make it valid.

Comment: Thank you so much @AnishB.  My logic is working for `polygon` and now working on logic for `MultiPolygon`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would parse GeoJSON into Postgis Geometry (TEXT) for `Polygon` (without considering holes) using Java 8 and Maven.

I reproduced the problem and solved it using these steps:

1. Get your GeoJSON sample and escaped it via FreeFormatter
2. Read the raw JSON into a JSONObject
3. Get a JSONArray for all `features` in the GeoJSON
4. Process `features` and extract an ArrayList of all coordinates for each `Polygon` present in `features`.
5. Set up Postgis template for Geometry TEXT datatype `POLYGON(lng1 lat1,lng2 lat2,...)`
6. Concatinate extracted coordinates of each Polygon in to Postgis template.
7. Add all results (`POLYGON(lng1 lat1,lng2 lat2,...)`) generated to an ArrayList.

```java
package com.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.*;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Escaped geojson via https://www.freeformatter.com/json-escape.html
        String geojson = "{\r\n  \"type\": \"FeatureCollection\",\r\n  \"name\": \"Some Boundary\",\r\n  \"crs\": {\r\n    \"type\": \"name\",\r\n    \"properties\": {\r\n      \"name\": \"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84\"\r\n    }\r\n  },\r\n  \"features\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"type\": \"Feature\",\r\n      \"properties\": {\r\n        \"State_Name\": \"ABC\",\r\n        \"State_Code\": \"01\"\r\n      },\r\n      \"geometry\": {\r\n        \"type\": \"Polygon\",\r\n        \"coordinates\": [\r\n          [\r\n            [\r\n              76.767318,\r\n              33.228753\r\n            ],\r\n            [\r\n              76.767318,\r\n              33.228753\r\n            ]\r\n          ]\r\n        ]\r\n      }\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"type\": \"Feature\",\r\n      \"properties\": {\r\n        \"State_Name\": \"DEF\",\r\n        \"State_Code\": \"02\"\r\n      },\r\n      \"geometry\": {\r\n        \"type\": \"Polygon\",\r\n        \"coordinates\": [\r\n          [\r\n            [\r\n              79.008814,\r\n              31.115041\r\n            ],\r\n            [\r\n              79.008814,\r\n              31.115041\r\n            ]\r\n          ]\r\n        ]\r\n      }\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"type\": \"Feature\",\r\n      \"properties\": {\r\n        \"State_Name\": \"GHI\",\r\n        \"State_Code\": \"03\"\r\n      },\r\n      \"geometry\": {\r\n        \"type\": \"Polygon\",\r\n        \"coordinates\": [\r\n          [\r\n            [\r\n              76.942524,\r\n              30.383268\r\n            ],\r\n            [\r\n              76.850815,\r\n              30.717589\r\n            ],\r\n            [\r\n              76.852673,\r\n              30.718222\r\n            ],\r\n            [\r\n              76.853471,\r\n              30.718813\r\n            ]\r\n          ]\r\n        ]\r\n      }\r\n    }\r\n  ]\r\n}";

        JSONObject geojsonObj = new JSONObject(geojson);
        System.out.println("\n-- Input: GeoJSON object");
        System.out.println(geojsonObj);

        // Get features
        JSONArray features = geojsonObj.getJSONArray("features");
        
        // Extract polygon Coordinates from each feature to an ArrayList
        List<JSONArray> polygonCoordinates = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < features.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject feature = features.getJSONObject(i);
            
            // Get Geometry from each Feature and parse raw coordinates (double)
            JSONObject geometry = feature.getJSONObject("geometry");
            if (geometry.getString("type").equals("Polygon")) {
                JSONArray coordinates = geometry.getJSONArray("coordinates");
                polygonCoordinates.add(coordinates.getJSONArray(0));
            }
        }

        // Set up Postgis geometry string to be formatted
        String polygonTemplate = "POLYGON((%s))";
        List<String> postgisGeometries = new ArrayList<>();
        // System.out.println(polygonCoordinates);

        // Traverse coordinates for each Polygon
        for (JSONArray coordinates : polygonCoordinates) {

            // Traverse long, lat for each coordinates
            String postgisCoordinates = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.length(); i++) {

                // Keep in mind that in GeoJSON, the order of coordinates are [longitude, latitude]
                double longitude = coordinates.getJSONArray(i).getDouble(0);
                double latitude = coordinates.getJSONArray(i).getDouble(1);

                // Concat longitude and latitude into Postgis coordinates format (long1 lat1,long2 lat2,...)
                if (i == coordinates.length() - 1) {
                    // if this is the last pair of long, lat -> no comma
                    postgisCoordinates += longitude + " " + latitude;
                } else {
                    postgisCoordinates += longitude + " " + latitude + ",";
                }
            }
            
            // Create Postgis Polygon Geometry Text: format postgisCoordinates into polygonTenmplate
            String polygonGeometryText = polygonTemplate.formatted(postgisCoordinates);

            // Add polygonGeometryText to postgisGeometries (our final output)
            postgisGeometries.add(polygonGeometryText);
        }



        // Print result: each geometry from List
        System.out.println("\n--- Output: List of Postgis POLYGON geometry (as TEXT)");
        for (String postgisGeometry : postgisGeometries) {
            System.out.println(postgisGeometry);
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### Input: GeoJSON object

```
{"features":[{"geometry":{"coordinates":[[[76.767318,33.228753],[76.767318,33.228753]]],"type":"Polygon"},"type":"Feature","properties":{"State_Code":"01","State_Name":"ABC"}},{"geometry":{"coordinates":[[[79.008814,31.115041],[79.008814,31.115041]]],"type":"Polygon"},"type":"Feature","properties":{"State_Code":"02","State_Name":"DEF"}},{"geometry":{"coordinates":[[[76.942524,30.383268],[76.850815,30.717589],[76.852673,30.718222],[76.853471,30.718813]]],"type":"Polygon"},"type":"Feature","properties":{"State_Code":"03","State_Name":"GHI"}}],"crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"}},"name":"Some Boundary","type":"FeatureCollection"}
```

#### Output: List of Postgis POLYGON geometry (as TEXT)

```
POLYGON((76.767318 33.228753,76.767318 33.228753))
POLYGON((79.008814 31.115041,79.008814 31.115041))
POLYGON((76.942524 30.383268,76.850815 30.717589,76.852673 30.718222,76.853471 30.718813))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and improvment. one quick thing before i try this, will it work for multipolygon as well...

Comment: @David you need to modify this part in order for it to work for **MultiPolygon**: ```if (geometry.getString("type").equals("Polygon")) {
                JSONArray coordinates = geometry.getJSONArray("coordinates");
                polygonCoordinates.add(coordinates.getJSONArray(0));
            }```. Basically, it require to change `coordinates.getJSONArray(0)` into `coordinates.getJSONArray(0).getJSONArray(0)`, because **MultiPolygon** is an array of **Polygon**. But this could break if there are holes within Polygon and you need to modify the logic for that case.